# Trig limit question involving cot

Tags: calculus, limits

How would I solve the following trig limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{4x}{\cot 3x}$$

This is what I did

$$\frac{4}{3} \frac{\sin3x}{\cos3x}$$

$$\frac{4}{3} (\frac{\sin3x}{3x}) (\frac{\cos3x}{1})$$

limit equals $\frac{4}{3}$ would this be correct.

Comment: it is an hw question but I am interested in hearing the detail...

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: I formatted your questions using MathJax. Please make sure I got it correct. Regards

Comment: @Amazoti it is correct. Indeed

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{4x}{\cot 3x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\, (4x) \frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 3x} =4\cdot 0 \cdot \frac 01 = 0.$$

The main problem you had was the result of a few mistakes in the your algebra when manipulating the function.

Comment: Fernando - is this clear now? Your main problem was a few mistakes in you algebra, which led to your evaluation of a *different* limit than the one given.

Comment: Hmm I know I did it incorrect now but I am not sure where I made my error.

Comment: your $\dfrac{\sin 3x}{\cos 3x}$ term was correct, but you forgot the $x$ from the original equation, and you introduced the fraction $\dfrac 43$ which should have been just the original $4$. So we need $(4x)\dfrac{\sin 3x}{\cos 3x}$.

Comment: $\dfrac{4x}{\cot 3x} = 4x \tan 3x = (4x) \dfrac{\sin 3x}{\cos 3x}$ or alternatively, $\dfrac{4x}{\cot 3x} = \dfrac{4x}{\dfrac{\cos 3x}{\sin 3x}} = \dfrac{4x \sin 3x}{\cos 3x} = 4x\cdot \dfrac{\sin 3x}{\cos 3x}$

Comment: Fernando, is this any clearer now? All that was done, before evaluating the limit, was rewriting the function to an equivalent form which allowed us to find the limit.

Comment: Yes it makes sense, I see my error especially when I saw how you wrote 4xsin3x/cos(3x), thanks.

Comment: One thing that still kind of confuses me is how sin3x/cos3x end up being zero I think it would end up being one.

Comment: because sin3x/cos3x can it not be (sin3x/3x) (1/cos3x)

Comment: No. $\sin (3\cdot 0) = \sin(0) = 0$, $\cos (3\cdot 0) = \cos (0) = 1.$ So $\dfrac{\sin (0)}{\cos (0)} = \dfrac 01 = 0.$ And this, in turn, is multiplied by $4\cdot 0 = 0$. There's no reason for dividing $\sin(3x)$ by $3x$. The (3x) is the argument of both $\sin$ and $\cos$. If the problem involved $3x$ in the denominator, then yes $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(3x)/3x$ would equal 1. But you can't introduce that term $3x$ without changing the problem.

Comment: Oh I see it makes sense thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{4x}{\cot 3x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} 4 x \tan{3x} =  \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (4 x) (3 x) = 0$$.

Comment: Why make this step $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} 4 x \tan{3x} =  \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (4 x) (3 x)$? The LHS is just $0\cdot0$.

Comment: To help show where the OP made a mistake.  He had a fraction flipped and therefore got a constant.

Comment: oohh! Well done.